# Removing duplicate lines from a list based on specific columns

Tags: c#

I believe that this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324066/distinct-a-list-of-records-based-on-two-column-using-groupby) but I was not able to apply the same solution.

I have a list with several columns:

```
    public struct InfoForGraph
    {
        public float a{ get; set; }
        public double b{ get; set; }
        public double c { get; set; }
        public double d { get; set; }
        public double e { get; set; }
        public double f { get; set; }
        public double g { get; set; }
        public double h { get; set; }
        public double i { get; set; }
        public double j { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to remove duplicate lines from this list but only if specific fields match. If I do a distinct with the whole table, these lines will not be erased. Also, I don't care with the repeated lines, I just wanna keep one of them.

Input:

```
2.67|1.84|420|400|1608039|808|3117|1|2|3|4
2.68|1.84|420|401|1608039|808|3269|1|2|3|4
```

Output expected:

```
2.67|1.84|420|400|1608039|808|3117|1|2|3|4
```

So, if columns 1,2,5,6,8,9,10 have the same value, I should keep only the first return (deleting the 2nd, 3rd, where all these fields match.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For simplicity, I narrowed down your condition to say that two objects are equal if `InfoForGraph.b` and `InfoForGraph.c` are equal.** You get the idea and change your comparer as you like.

```
public class InfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<InfoForGraph>
{
    public bool Equals(InfoForGraph x, InfoForGraph y)
    {
        if (x.b == y.b && x.c == y.c)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(InfoForGraph obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.b.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.c.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call `Distinct()` on it.

```
var unique = list.Distinct(new InfoComparer());
```

Comment: I should mention that to be complete you should check for null objects and other such anomalies/errors in `GetHashCode()` as well as `Equals()`.

Comment: Wouldn't two objects which are supposed to be equal get different hashcodes? For example: {b=1, c=2} and {b=1, c=3}

Comment: @MaorVeitsman I simplified OP's conditions, so in my examples two objects are equal if `Obj1.b == Obj2.b && Obj1.c == Obj2.c`. So under these conditions your example objects are not deemed equal.

Comment: What formula would you use if the 'or' statement is used?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman that's a fantastic question. I might have to think about it. 
**Edit:** Do you know an answer?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman I asked this in a [separate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601130/302248), and turns out you cannot really use OR in an equality comparer as it violates fundamental assumptions of the comparer which is equality being transitive.